# Dell XPS 15 9500 Ubuntu 20.04 wifi connection not working anymore

Tags: networking, wireless, dell

installed ubuntu 20.04 on Dell xps 15.
First dual boot, two weeks ago removed windows and installed ubuntu alone.
wifi thru android hotspot worked well during dual boot and after.
Two days ago laptop couldnt connect to hotspot and displayed pop up:
"connection failed; Activation of network connection failed"

output of:
sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager

-- Logs begin at Sun 2021-09-26 08:34:38 +07, end at Mon 2021-09-27 22:45:28 +07. --
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.4229] NetworkManager (version 1.22.10) is starting... (for the first time)
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.4229] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivit>
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.4311] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.4343] manager[0x55637652e030]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.4343] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5101] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5101] hostname: hostname changed from (none) to "XPSUB"
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5103] dns-mgr[0x55637651d290]: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=symlink, plugin=systemd-resolved
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5111] rfkill0: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/ieee80211/phy0/r>
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5113] manager[0x55637652e030]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set disabled
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5113] manager[0x55637652e030]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5148] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-dev>
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5170] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-de>
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5175] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-devi>
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5182] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-dev>
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5188] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-dev>
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5200] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; disabled by state file
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5201] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5201] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5203] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5210] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/l>
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5211] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5211] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5213] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5236] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5239] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5243] device (wlp0s20f3): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5248] manager: (wlp0s20f3): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5256] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: >
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5279] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5285] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi now disabled by radio killswitch
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5300] manager: startup complete
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5310] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Sep 27 22:36:02 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756962.5313] supplicant: wpa_supplicant running
Sep 27 22:36:23 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632756983.8189] agent-manager: agent[a6c635a99a51236e,:1.79/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
Sep 27 22:37:27 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632757047.2261] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Sep 27 22:37:27 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632757047.4315] audit: op="radio-control" arg="wireless-enabled" pid=2409 uid=1000 result="success"
Sep 27 22:37:27 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632757047.4318] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi now enabled by radio killswitch
Sep 27 22:37:27 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632757047.4775] sup-iface[0x556376543100,wlp0s20f3]: supports 5 scan SSIDs
Sep 27 22:37:27 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632757047.4786] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Sep 27 22:37:27 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632757047.4787] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlp0s20f3 created
Sep 27 22:37:27 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632757047.4791] manager: (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devi>
Sep 27 22:37:27 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632757047.4796] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface>
Sep 27 22:37:27 XPSUB NetworkManager[971]:   [1632757047.4806] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface>

Comment: While it’s easy to appreciate the frustration of losing network connectivity, it’s incredibly difficult to know which “things” you tried in the terminal. Could you [edit] your question to list what you have tried, what error messages you’ve received, and perhaps some of the log data in `/var/log/syslog` after a failed network connection attempt? This will make it more likely that you are offered a solution that you haven’t already tried, saving you (and others) the hassle of writing words that serve no purpose 

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`. Also read https://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask